# The subreport 'Subreport' could not be found at the specified location. RDLC Sub report

Tags: .net, wpf, reporting-services, report, rdlc

I'm working on WPF RDLC sub reporting part. I'm facing an issue in sub report. This is the issue

> The subreport 'Subreport' could not be found at the specified location
> F:\Upwork\Backup 21.01.09\RDLC_Subreport_WPF
> \NewSubreportWPF\SubReport.rdlc. Please verify that the subreport has
> been published and that the name is correct.

This is screenshot of issue.... [Report issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04GUW.png)

This is the repository can get the all file-- https://github.com/izzathali/RDLC_Subreport_WPF

**This is the MainWindow**
[Main Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyiEW.png)

**This is the screenshot of MainReport1**
[MainReport1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUcgt.png)

**This is the SubReport**
[SubReport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz8iT.png)

**This is the DataSet1**
[DataSet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSqDM.png)

**Parameter SubReport**
[Parameter SubReport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3kUO.png)

**SubReport Properties**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igbUL.png)

**This is the code of MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    private void btnExport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowReport();
    }
    private void ShowReport()
    {
        DataTable dtOrders = MainReport(Convert.ToInt32(txtSearch.Text));
        ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
        viewer.Reset();
        viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"F:\Upwork\Backup 21.01.09\RDLC_Subreport_WPF\NewSubreportWPF\MainReport1.rdlc";
        ReportDataSource ds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dtOrders);
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds);
        viewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(OrderDetailsSubreportProcessing);
        viewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

        string[] streamIds;
        Warning[] warnings;

        string mimeType = string.Empty;
        string encoding = string.Empty;
        string extension = string.Empty;

        string fileName = @"E:\Report.pdf";
        byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, bytes);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);
    }

    private DataTable MainReport(int OrderID)
    {
        
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string conStr = @"Data Source=IZZATH-BIN-IBRA\SQLEXPRESS2019;Initial Catalog=POS1;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            string query = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Order] WHERE OrderId ='" + OrderID + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                dt.Load(reader);
            }
        }

        return dt;

    }

    void OrderDetailsSubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        int orderID = int.Parse(e.Parameters["OrderId"].Values[0].ToString());
        DataTable dtOrderDetails = Subreport(orderID);
        ReportDataSource ds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dtOrderDetails);
        e.DataSources.Add(ds);
    }

    private DataTable Subreport(int OrderID)
    {
        
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string conStr = @"Data Source=IZZATH-BIN-IBRA\SQLEXPRESS2019;Initial Catalog=POS1;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            string query = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[OrderDetail] WHERE OrderId ='" + OrderID + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                dt.Load(reader);
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: the error is obvious. are you sure that the file in the path "F:\Upwork\Backup 21.01.09\RDLC_Subreport_WPF \NewSubreportWPF\SubReport.rdlc" is actually available?

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono yes. it is available

Comment: Did you map the parameter from the main report to the subreport?